# value from select row material-ui-datatable React

Tags: python, django, reactjs, material-ui

i need get value from a cell in selected row

this my table

```
  <DataTables
                   height={'auto'}
                   selectable={true}
                   showRowHover={true}
                   filterHintText ={this.props.filtro}
                   title = {this.props.titulo}
                   showHeaderToolbar={true}
                   columns={TABLE_COLUMNS}
                   data={this.state.data}
                   showCheckboxes={true}
                   onRowSelection={this.handleRowSelection}
                   onFilterValueChange={this.handleFilterValueChange}
                   onSortOrderChange={this.handleSortOrderChange}
                   enableSelectAll={true}
                   page={1}
                   count={100}
               />);
```

and this is my method

```
 handleRowSelection(selectedRows) {
    console.log('Valor: ' + selectedRows);
  }
```

and just get a row id, i dont know how get cell data from selected row i try this form but results undifinded

console.log('Valor: ' + selectedRows[1]);

Comment: What DataTables library are you using?

Comment: Material-Ui-datatable, i did it this way var valor =this.state.data[selectedRows]['id'];

Comment: Yeah i was gonna say, if you have the id then you could just look up the data yourself.  nice!

Comment: thanks, Do you know any method or way to reload the data with this library?